# How does React key works?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, virtual-dom

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class App extends React.Component{
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
         list: [{id: 1,val: 'aa'}, {id: 2, val: 'bb'}, {id: 3, val: 'cc'}]
      }
   }

   click() {
      this.state.list.reverse()
      this.setState({})
   }

   render() {
      return (
            <ul>
                <div onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>reverse</div>
                {
                 this.state.list.map(function(item, index) {
                  return (
                            <Li key={item.id} val={item.val}></Li>
                  )
                 }.bind(this))
                }
            </ul>
      )
   }
}

class Li extends React.Component{
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
   }
   componentDidMount() {
      console.log('===did===')
   }
   componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
      console.log('===mount====')
   }
   render() {
      return (
            <li>
                {this.props.val}
                <input type="text"></input>
            </li>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

when I set key as `item.id`, and I set three input tags `a`, `b`, `c`;

when I click reverse, the component Li will mount, input will reverse

when I change key as `index`, when I click reverse, the component Li update, and the input tag will not change,

I want to know how does it happen? Does Anyone have found out how key works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @DuncanThacker explained the `key` is used to identify unique elements, so that between 2 render passes React knows if an element is a new thing or an updated thing. Remember that React diffs each render to determine what actually changed in the DOM.

Now to explain the behavior you're seeing:

> when I set key as `item.id`, and I set three input tags `a, b, c`;
>
> when I click reverse, the component Li will mount, input will reverse

When you use `id` as `key` you can re-order the array but React will only create and mount the node the *first* time. You are outputting `===mount===` inside `componentWillUpdate`, which is why you see that misleading output, but React is only updating the nodes (moving them as needed). The state of the inner `input` also follows each `<Li>` component to its new position, since React correctly understands that the `<Li>` *moved*, not simply re-drawn with different content.

> when I change key as `index`, when I click reverse, the component Li
>   update, and the input tag will not change

When you use `index` as `key` React effectively sees each render pass as rendering the array in the *same order* but with different content, since each element's `key` is the same `index` no matter what order the array content is in. This is also why the inner `input` stays in the same place, even though the `val` label is rendered in a different position. *And this is exactly why you should not use `index` as `key`.*

You could illustrate it like this:

```
|-----------------------|---------------------|--------------------------|
|        Before         |        After        |          Change          |
|-----------------------|---------------------|--------------------------|
```

**Array:**

```
|-----------------------|---------------------|--------------------------|
| { id: 1, val: "A" }   | { id: 3, val: "C" } | Moved from last to first |
| { id: 2, val: "B" }   | { id: 2, val: "B" } | None                     |
| { id: 3, val: "C" }   | { id: 1, val: "A" } | Moved from first to last |
|-----------------------|---------------------|--------------------------|
```

**Render `key` from `index`:**

```
|-----------------------|---------------------|--------------------------|
| <Li key=0 val="A">    | <Li key=0 val="C">  | Val changed "A" to "C"   |
| <Li key=1 val="B">    | <Li key=1 val="B">  | None                     |
| <Li key=2 val="C">    | <Li key=2 val="A">  | Val changed "C" to "A"   |
|-----------------------|---------------------|--------------------------|
```

**Render `key` from `item.id`:**

```
|-----------------------|---------------------|--------------------------|
| <Li key=1 val="A">    | <Li key=3 val="C">  | Moved from bottom to top |
| <Li key=2 val="B">    | <Li key=2 val="B">  | None                     |
| <Li key=3 val="C">    | <Li key=1 val="A">  | Moved from top to bottom |
|-----------------------|---------------------|--------------------------|
```

***Summary:*** you should always use `id` or some other unique element identifier as `key`.

See also: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 0):

The "key" attribute is used by React to determine whether to render a brand new instance of the component, or whether the update an existing one. So using the item id as the key will mean that the component for that item will not be destroyed and re-created. If you add a new item to the list it will create a new component, and if you remove an item it will destroy the old one, but if you update an item without change its ID, the component will just update.

It's useful for dynamic lists because it reduces weird cases where a mounted component switches from rendering one list item to rendering another list item, when really it should be a brand new component instance.